I'm fine-tuning a small GPT model but I can't get it to use my GPU
I’m currently fine-tuning a GPT-2 distilled model with approximately 130M parameters on 8 years' worth of my WhatsApp chats. I’ve prepared a labeled dataset consisting of around 1 million sequences, each with 512 tokens. Below is the portion of code I am using for training:
def train_epoch(model, inputs, labels, batch_size, optimizer, scheduler, device):

    model.train()

    total_loss = 0
    iter = int(len(inputs) / batch_size)
    scaler = GradScaler()

    inputs=inputs.to(device)
    labels=labels.to(device)

    for i in range(iter):

        print(f"Iter {i + 1} of {iter}")

        inputs_batch= inputs[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        labels_batch = labels[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]

        inputs_batch, labels_batch = inputs_batch.to(device), labels_batch.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        print(inputs_batch.shape)

        with autocast("cuda"):
            outputs = model(inputs_batch, labels=labels_batch)
            loss = outputs.loss

        scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        scaler.step(optimizer)
        scaler.update()

        total_loss += loss.item()

        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

    avg_loss = total_loss / iter
    print(f"Epoch average loss: {avg_loss}")

learning_rate = 5e-5
batch_size = 16
epochs = 100

model_name = 'GroNLP/gpt2-small-italian'
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("GroNLP/gpt2-small-italian")

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

total_steps = batch_size * epochs
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=total_steps)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)

inputs = train_dataset[0]
labels = train_dataset[1]

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1} of {epochs}")
    indices = torch.randperm(len(train_dataset[0]))
    inputs= inputs[indices]
    labels = labels[indices]
    train_epoch(model, inputs, labels, batch_size, optimizer, scheduler, device)

The training process is taking an extraordinarily long time—hundreds of hours in total. I've tried various methods to get the code to use my GPU, but without success. I've checked the compatibility of PyTorch and TensorFlow versions with CUDA multiple times. CUDA is available, the version is correct, and PyTorch recognizes my GPU. I can see that GPU memory is being utilized during training, so the issue might be with the code itself. Since this is my first project, the problem might be obvious to experienced users like you but not to me.

If GPU memory is being used during training, what makes you say that the model is not using the GPU? Is it just because training is taking a long time?

The fact that the GPU processor is not being used and that it would take 90 days to complete the training. Maybe I'am using sequences that are too long? Maybe my dataset is too large?

How do you determine that the GPU is not being used? And what GPU are you using?

I am using an RTX 3060 and when the code is running I check at the task manager and notice no GPU processor usage, just CPU

Have your training loop run print(loss.device) to see what device is being used

It prints "cuda: 0". Maybe my code is really using the gpu, but it is still very slow and the gpu processor usage doesn't change. Do you think it is normal?

You should be checking and posting the output of nvidia-smi while training is running.

When I run the command it says that my overall GPU usage is 70% but on the task manager this is not the case and stays at around 0%. Maybe the task manager isn't properly measuring it's usage?

@MarcoFerroni I would trust nvidia-smi over the task manager
